# DataGridView datetime column failed to sort

Tags: c#, datagridview

I know ther are a lot of questions like this but i have not found one that helps my case.

I have a DataGridView and i insert rows and columns without a dataset but from a list. I check if the column will contain a datetime type and its successful:

```
string[] formats = {"M/d/yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy",
                        "d/M/yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy",
                        "yyyy/M/d", "yyyy/MM/dd",
                        "M-d-yyyy", "MM-dd-yyyy",
                        "d-M-yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy",
                        "yyyy-M-d", "yyyy-MM-dd",
                        "M.d.yyyy", "MM.dd.yyyy",
                        "d.M.yyyy", "dd.MM.yyyy",
                        "yyyy.M.d", "yyyy.MM.dd",
                        "M,d,yyyy", "MM,dd,yyyy",
                        "d,M,yyyy", "dd,MM,yyyy",
                        "yyyy,M,d", "yyyy,MM,dd",
                        "M d yyyy", "MM dd yyyy",
                        "d M yyyy", "dd MM yyyy",
                        "yyyy M d", "yyyy MM dd",
                        "dd MMMM yyyy", "dd MMM yy"
                       };
        List<string> _columnList = new List<string>();
        List<HtmlNode> _descList = new List<HtmlNode>();
        DateTime date;
        GetResultsDecendants(_descList, targetNode);
        foreach( var _desc in _descList)
        {
            foreach( string dtFormat in formats)
            {
                if(DateTime.TryParseExact(_desc.InnerText, dtFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
                {
                    finalDateFormat = dtFormat;
                }
            }
            if ( finalDateFormat != null)
            {
                _columnList.Add(_desc.Name+" -Date");
            }
            _columnList.Add(_desc.Name);
```

After i create the coluns i set the specific column's format to the correct format

```
dataGridView.Columns[colHasDate].DefaultCellStyle.Format = finalDateFormat;
```

I even make sure that the value of every cell in that column has a type of DateTime

```
if (colList[colindex].Contains("Date"))
                {
                    dgvRow.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
                    {
                        Value = listItem.InnerText,
                        ValueType = typeof(DateTime)
                    }
                    );
                }
```

But when i try to sort it by clicking the column name it almost fails, it will show the oldest first but from that its almost random. 
Please help.

Comment: The posted code is confusing. It is difficult to understand what the two `foreach` loops are doing, can you describe what the code is trying to accomplish here? In addition, I cannot understand why you would use `DataGridViewImageCell` and set its `ValueType` of `DataTime`… this is confusing and definitely won’t work as you expect. If you want to display a “date” in the grid… the cell “type” would be a string/text cell. Again, the posted code is very confusing; you may want to elaborate more on what the code is actually doing.

Comment: @JohnG 1st i am sorry about the DataGridViewImageCell its supposed to be TextBoxCell( still doesnt sort correctly). In descendantList the re nodes that i want to use in the datagrid so the 1st foreach is for that list, the second foreach is for the types of dates in the list above so i know what type it is, so i can put the type in the cell formating after. ( i am making a web scraper so i wont know if a website has dates in their results or no) Hope that helps

Comment: What are you expecting to happen in the inner `foreach` loop? From what I can tell the loop `foreach( string dtFormat in formats)` is not doing what you think it is. Example if `_desc.InnerText` is a “valid” date… it will “ALWAYS” return the “dd MMM yy” format (the last format in the list). I question the purpose of this `foreach` loop.

Comment: @JohnG i am usng this loop to find the type of the format, for example in the website that i do the tests the date in their results is in this format "dd MMMM yyyy" and i chedk in debug mode and it got the correct format and set the cell format in this exact format

Comment: I do not think the `DateTime.TryParseExact` works that way. The for each loop is not going to tell you if the “date format” is correct. The line: `if(DateTime.TryParseExact(_desc.InnerText, dtFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))` will return “true” if `_desc.InnerText` is a valid date. The `dtFormat` is simply the format it will use to format the “valid” date.

Comment: Therefore, assuming `_desc.InnerText` contains a valid date, the first time through the `foreach` loop `dtFormat` will be “M/d/yyyy”, the ‘if’ statement will return true, since the date is valid, and will obligingly set `finalDateFormat = dtFormat;` Then execution returns to the beginning of the `foreach` loop where `dtFormat` will become the “MM/dd/yyyy” format.

Comment: Since the date is valid, the `finalDateFormat = dtFormat;` line gets executed. This continues until the end of the list is reached where as I state previously that if the date is valid the `finalDateFormat` variable will ALWAYS end up in the “dd MMM yy” format.

Comment: @JohnG I see..i thought that only with the correct format the TryParseExact would be true but even if that happens then that means the format in the cells would change, or thats the cause that it wont sort?

Comment: I am guessing what you are seeing in the sort is most likely a “lexical” sort order. This obviously will not work with dates. Regardless of which date “format” (MM/dd/yyyy…) is selected, when it gets to the `DataGridView`… the `DataGridView` is going to see it as a “string” not a “date.” Applying a default cell style as a “Date” will still sort the column as a “string.” I highly recommend you use a `DataTable` with a `DateTime` column. Setting the `DataGridView.DataSource` to this table will give you the sorting you are looking for without having to add any code.

Comment: @JohnG Thank you very much for all the help you have provided, unfortunately i cant find a way to dynamicaly create a dataSource since this application is not for one specific website, that means i wont know if the results will have an image or date or anything else

Comment: Your last comment indicates you have not researched enough about what you are asking. Initially this was a question about sorting not working. Now it has turned into something completely different. Can you clarify what your question is? Your last comment: _”i cant find a way to dynamicaly create a dataSource since this application is not for one specific website, that means i wont know if the results will have an image or date or anything else”_ … this sounds like something else.

Comment: Is the question about the sorting or getting the results from a website? You should narrow what you are asking, as your question is getting broader with each comment.

Comment: @JohnG Oh no, the question was about sorting the datagridview column and still is, what i said in the last comment was more of a sidenote, a reason why i dont have a dataset